# tkinter stretching widgets within a frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, raspbian

I'm currently trying to make a basic GUI with 5 buttons stuck on the bottom of the screen within a frame. What I have currently is 2 buttons in a frame. The frame is packed to the bottom. I'm trying to have those 2 button fill the frame.

```
##IMPORTS--------------------------------------------
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font
##GUIWindow------------------------------------------
window = tkinter.Tk()                   
screen_w = window.winfo_screenwidth()  
screen_h = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry('%dx%d' % (screen_w, screen_h))
window.title("betaV00")
myFont = tkinter.font.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 12, weight = "bold")
##WIDGET_BottomButtons---------------------------------
h=6
bot_frame = Frame(window, height = int(screen_h/10), width = int(screen_w))
bot_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

btn_HOME = Button(bot_frame, text="Home", font=myFont, bg='green', fg='white', height=h)
btn_HOME.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
btn_LEDS = Button(bot_frame, text="LEDS", font=myFont, bg='black', fg='green', height=h)
btn_LEDS.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

bot_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
bot_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
##-----------------------------------------------------

window.mainloop()
```

I can get it to work if the buttons are not in a frame. What is currently happening is the two buttons are not stretching and are placed in the middle side by side. What can/should I do to have those buttons expand?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `Frame` that the two `Button` Widgets are in is not being given any kind of instruction on how much of its parent it should be occupying, therefore it simply expands to the minimum size it can to contain all of its children.

In this example, if you wanted them to expand in the x-axis only (which I'm assuming you do as you've given them a static height) you would need to add the attribute `fill="x"` to your `.pack()` command on the `Frame` `bot_frame` and add the attribute `sticky="NESW"` to both of the `.pack()` commands on the two `Button` widgets.

This will look like the below:

```
##IMPORTS--------------------------------------------
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font
##GUIWindow------------------------------------------
window = tkinter.Tk()                   
screen_w = window.winfo_screenwidth()  
screen_h = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry('%dx%d' % (screen_w, screen_h))
window.title("betaV00")
myFont = tkinter.font.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 12, weight = "bold")
##WIDGET_BottomButtons---------------------------------
h=6
bot_frame = Frame(window)
bot_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill="x") #here

btn_HOME = Button(bot_frame, text="Home", font=myFont, bg='green', fg='white', height=h)
btn_HOME.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky="NESW") #here
btn_LEDS = Button(bot_frame, text="LEDS", font=myFont, bg='black', fg='green', height=h)
btn_LEDS.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky="NESW") #and here

bot_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
bot_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
##-----------------------------------------------------

window.mainloop()
```

The above should achieve your desired result.